# Question on the .call() Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, method-call

I need help understanding code that doesn't explicitly call out it's relation to other parts of the code (a resource that details where and why this occurs would be hugely beneficial). I am sorry that I do not know how to better refer to this type of code or even if it has a particular name.

As an example, I have included the code below. `.call(arguments)` does not explicitly refer to any function. Yet, it causes `sumArgumentsCorrectly` to execute with the list of numbers `(1,2,3,4,5)` passed in as arguments (which were not given the name arguments in the original `sumArgumentsCorrectly` execution). This is all very confusing to someone new and unfortunately all the resources I can find on the .call() method instead refer to its redirection of .this() and not detailing how it is recalling its own function without explicitly naming it.

```
function sumArgumentsCorrectly(){
    return [].slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(acc,next){
        return acc + next;
    },0)
}

console.log(sumArgumentsCorrectly(1,2,3,4,5)) // 15
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function sumArgumentsCorrectlyV2(){
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(acc,next){
        return acc + next;
    },0)
}

function sumArgumentsCorrectlyV3(){
    return Array.from(arguments).reduce(function(acc,next){
        return acc + next;
    },0)
}

console.log(sumArgumentsCorrectlyV2(1,2,3,4,5)) // 15

console.log(sumArgumentsCorrectlyV3(1,2,3,4,5)) // 15
```

I have added two different version of that code. As @Amy commented `arguments` are not array but array like objects. It has index accessible properties and a length property and doesn't have functions like `slice` or `reduce`. In order to execute array function you need access the function and pass the array like instance. When you calling the `call` method and passing the `arguments` as a parameter you are telling the compiler execute this function on this instance.